# Execute statement 500 times ignoring exceptions

Tags: python, exception

```py
import random 
import string
from bitcoinrpc.authproxy import AuthServiceProxy, JSONRPCException

rpc_port = 18444
rpc_user = 'user3'
rpc_password = 'pass3'

def wallet_name(size): 
    
    generate_wallet = ''.join([random.choice(string.punctuation + string.ascii_letters) 
                         for n in range(size)]) 
                        
    return generate_wallet
 
try:
    rpc_connection = AuthServiceProxy("http://%s:%s@127.0.0.1:%s"%(rpc_user,rpc_password,rpc_port))

    i=0
    while i < 500:
        wallet = wallet_name(20)              
        result = rpc_connection.createwallet(wallet)        
        i += 1
  

except Exception:
    pass
```

I want this code to try and create 500 wallets but it stops at 2-3. If I print the exception its giving an error related to incorrect file name or file path but the exception should be ignored and try creating wallet with next string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the point of creating 500 randomly named wallets, when you're not even saving the names?

```
    for i in range(500):
        wallet = wallet_name(20)
        try:
            result = rpc_connection.createwallet(wallet)        
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: Thanks. That works. I also added a `print` statement to see what all names were tried.